# Selecting a value from the Python toolbox drop-down list of an ArcPy script in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, tool-validation

I created a script. I would like the user to be able to select a value from the drop-down list. Once the value is selected, I would like this value to be displayed on my cover page that I created.
However, when I execute the code, instead of a single value that is displayed, all the values in the drop-down list are displayed as the title of the cover page.
Here is so attached my code and the result that the performance produces.

```
class ToolValidator:
    # Class to add custom behavior and properties to the tool and tool parameters.

    def __init__(self):
        # set self.params for use in other function
        import arcpy, os
        
        self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()
        
    def initializeParameters(self):
        # Customize parameter properties. 
        # This gets called when the tool is opened.               
        return
        
    
    def updateParameters(self):
        # Modify parameter values and properties.
        # This gets called each time a parameter is modified, before 
        # standard validation.
        aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT") 
        map1 = aprx.listMaps("Map1")[0]
        cov = aprx.listLayouts("Mapbook_global")[0]
        lyr_planches = map1.listLayers("assemblage_carro_11000_5000")[0]

        ## titre 
        TheRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(lyr_planches) 
        liste = []
        for TheRow in TheRows: 
            liste.append(TheRow.cis)              
        TheName = list(set(liste))       
        title = TheName
        titleTxt =cov.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT","title")[0]
        titleTxt.text = title
                 
        self.params[0].value = lyr_planches
        self.params[1].filter.list = TheName
        
        return
```

Comment: The first rule of ArcPy cursors is "Don't use `arcpy.SearchCursor`" (Use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` instead). Python best practice is to use `lower_case` variable names and `UpperCase` class names. Your code goes out of its way to make a `list` then a `set` the a `list` again, and calls that (eventually) `title`, so it shouldn't be a surprise that all the values are present. You haven't included the code where the value is used.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the titleTxt to title which is a list which make all the values in the drop-down list to be displayed

```
TheName = list(set(liste))       
title = TheName
```

Instead, move that part to the main script body

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
   title = parameters[1].valueAsText
 
   aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT") 
   map1 = aprx.listMaps("Map1")[0]
   cov = aprx.listLayouts("Mapbook_global")[0]
   
   titleTxt =cov.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT","title")[0]
   titleTxt.text = title
```

Comment: Merci pour votre retour. J'ai repris et ça marche.

Comment: If it works, mark it as the correct answer.